# iOS8 iPhone 5 Mobile Safari cannot be inspected by Desktop Safari 7.0.6 .. "No Inspectable Applications"

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, ios8

I'm trying to debug a website on my iPhone. I used to be able to just connect the iPhone to my Mac and open up Safari. I'd click "Develop" and see my phone in that menu, then I could see each of my open Mobile Safari tabs from there.

Now, with iOS8 it no longer shows the open tabs on my Mobile Safari and instead of my open tabs I get "No Inspectable Applications".

[image]

I've made sure that Web Inspector is enabled.

Settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Inspector is on.

I'm not trying to open the 'tab' in private mode.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or is this a bug with Apple?

Also, for what it's worth, I've reset both my phone and desktop, reset both safaris. Unplugged and reconnected the cable... I'm at a loss.

Comment: @Joe This is a different question. It is asking why that was happening for an open tab on mobile safari not for iOS native apps. Also, the accepted answer here is current, much more simple (just update Safari on desktop), and has 13 votes at the time of this comment, while that question's accepted answer has 0. Also, this is specifically regarding iOS 8. Not iOS 7. Please remove the "possible duplicate".

Comment: This happens to me all the time... I'll refresh the page on my iPad or leave it for a few minutes and the debug connection between my Mac and the iPad dies. It's so infuriating! Developing for iOS is such a pain

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Updating to Safari 7.1 (available in App Store updates today, September, 18 2014) on OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) enables remote debugging with iOS 8 Safari.

You don't need Yosemite.

Comment: That is very odd that they updated Safari yesterday to 7.0.6 and then today to 7.1. I have a few less hairs but thank you for the correct answer! (What is most aggravating is that I ran the updates that were available yesterday, today.) Then checked for updates again and nothing. Now I look after reading your comment and of course, an update for safari..)

Answer (score 5):

I found out that iOS 8 Mobile Safari can only be inspected by Safari 8 on the Mac. Safari 8 comes with Mac OSX Yosemite (which is in beta right now). Or, I guess you can get it by downloading the latest nightly build of Safari found here: http://nightly.webkit.org

Update: Now that Safari 7.1 has been released for OSX Mavericks, you can download it and it will work with iOS 8.

Comment: Hey @teewuane! I'm on Yosemite, IOS 8.1 and Safari 8.0. I'm getting "No Inspectable Applications" :( I've checked all my settings. I'm at a loss!

Comment: @Dustin I Just made sure this works for me. It's working on my iPhone 6, iPhone 5, and iPad mini. Does your phone show up in Devices menu of Desktop Safari? I'm assuming you have your settings set in iOS. `Settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Inspector = On` I know that "No Inspectable Applications" will show if you don't currently have Mobile Safari or the web app up and open on your iOS. Also, that menu won't automatically update when it's active. I had to click off and back onto it a few times. Any luck?

Answer (score 4):

I just realized in iOS 8 that there's a **setting in Safari** under advanced that allows for the Web Inspector to work.  I don't remember that in 7 but it may have been there.  That made everything start working for me.